# How to describe an image file path which is inside javascript file through codeigniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

For code requirement and security purpose I am calling image using its path  inside main.js file, but for normal php (without framework) it works in this way but problem is that  I am using Codeigniter and in codeigniter you can call using base_url() in  php file  but here image is inside js file so my question is how to specify image path  inside js with codeigniter.

```
var modifytop={

controlHTML: '<img src="assets/img/arrow.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />',
anchorkeyword: '#top',

 }
```

Comment: You can also prepend path with slash which will force browser to read location from the root i.e. `/assets/img/arrow.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `JS` cannot identify the `PHP`, `PHP` code will not execute.

So declare the `base_url()` in your `HTML` file.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
//your rest of js source links
</body>
</html>
```

Then use the `base_url` variable in the `JS` file.

```
var modifytop={

controlHTML: '<img src="'+base_url+'"assets/img/arrow.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />',
anchorkeyword: '#top',

 }
```

Set the base_url in config file as below

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/your-project-name/";
```

Comment: this is fine since quotes are illegal in a url, but most of the time it's safer to json encode stuff that you're passing to javascript.. `myvar = <?php echo json_encode($myvar); ?>` (no surrounding quotes).

Comment: also, you have some funky quotes in your controlHTML string

Comment: Surrounding codes are required. I have used earlier like you mentioned. But it gives me an error.

Comment: if you encode it like i suggested the quotes are not required, in fact, the quotes will break it. when you said you fixed it i thought you meant the json encode, not the string.. that's why i deleted the comment and upvoted.. all good, it works as is

Comment: Did you display it in the console?? If displayed what you are getting??

Comment: @Prabhu It is displaying localhost:81/myfolder/controller/assets

Comment: Have you set the `base_url` in `config.php` file under config folder??

Comment: Can you put your config['base_url'] value here?? so that i can fix your issue.

Comment: @Prabhu but  in console showing  VM119 back-to-top.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: base_url is not defined.

Comment: Have you defined it on the top of all your javascript source links?? It should be first and rest of the js files and js code later. See my answer. Hope it is understandable.

Comment: @Prabhu yes you are right now it's woking thanks once again.

Comment: Okay. Accept my answer to help other users.